# Fundamental Concepts of Mathematics: Definition of divisibility

Tags: combinatorics

1. Is it possible to have 50 coins, made up of pennies, dimes and quarters, that add up to $3?

   Explain.
2. Is it possible to have a combination of nickels, dimes and quarters that add up to $4.72? Explain.

Sorry, I need help with these 2 questions as mentioned above. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Formulate the problems mathematically. Let $P$ denote the number of pennies, $N$ the number of nickels, $D$ the number of dimes and $Q$ the number of quarters.

Question 1 is asking you if there is an integer solution to the pair of equations
$$P + 10D + 25Q = 300 \quad \text{and} \quad P+D+Q = 50$$

Question 2 is asking you if there is an integer solution to the single equation
$$5N + 10D + 25Q = 472$$

Play around with these for a while.

If you need more hints then ask.

Comment: Thank you. However, for the first question, I got 24D + 9Q = 250.

Comment: I guess that it can't be solved? I mean for both the first and 2nd question?

Comment: As in for the first question, there are no integer values that can satisfy D and Q of my equation 24D + 9Q = 250. Hence, there is no possible combination?

Comment: @randmkill: You're correct. But you should probably say why. (Hint: use a divisibility argument.)

Comment: 24D + 9Q = 3(8D + 3Q) Hence, 24D + 9Q is not divisible by 5, whereas 5 divides 250. Hence, it is not possible to get any integer combination of D and Q?

Comment: That's not quite right: $24D+9Q$ is divisible by $5$ when, say, $D=5$ and $Q=0$. But $24D+9Q$ is divisible by $3$, so ..... ?

Answer (score 1):

For the first, note that you're trying to have

\begin{align}
p + 10d + 25q &= 300 \\
p + d + q &= 50
\end{align}

Try eliminating a variable and see what you get.

For the second problem, note that any combination of nickels, dimes and quarters will have the form

$$5n + 10d + 25q = 5(n + 2d + 5q)$$

will be divisible by $5$. So can we ever get $472$?

Comment: As in for the first question, there are no integer values that can satisfy D and Q of my equation 24D + 9Q = 250. Hence, there is no possible combination? –